# Using strings scraped from a page to generate a list of start_urls for further scraping using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

please help,

I have collected a whole lot of strings from a realestate website's search results page that corresponds to porperty ids.  The site uses property ids to name pages containing information about individual properties that I want to collect.

How can I get my list of urls created by my first spider into the start_urls of another spider?

Thanks - im new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to have two spiders. A spider can `yield` a `scrapy.http.Request` object with a custom callback, to allow additional pages to be scraped based on the values parsed from an initial set of pages.

Let's look at an example:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request    

class SearchSpider(BaseSpider):
   ...
   start_urls = ['example.com/list_of_links.html']
   ...

   # Assume this is your "first" spider's parse method
   # It parses your initial search results page and generates a
   # list of URLs somehow.
   def parse(self, response):
     hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
     # For example purposes we just take every link
     for href in hxs.select('//a/@href]).extract():
       yield Request(href[0], callback=self.parse_search_url)

   def parse_search_url(self, response):
      # Here is where you would put what you were thinking of as your
      # "second" spider's parse method. It operates on the results of the
      # URLs scraped in the first parse method.
      pass
```

As you see in this example, the SearchSpider.parse method parses the "search results page" (or whatever) and yields a Request for each URL that it finds. So instead of writing those URLs to a file and trying to use them as the start_urls for a second spider, simply yield them with the callback set to another method in the same spider (here: parse_search_url).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow noob, I understand that it can be difficult to get your head around the `yield` method in Scrapy. If you don't manage to get the method @audiodude details above (which is the better way to scrape for a number of reasons), a 'workaround' I have used is to produce my urls (in LibreOffice or Excel) by employing the `Concatenate` function to add the correct punctuation for each line. Then simply copy and paste them into my spider e.g.

```
start_urls = [
  "http://example.com/link1",
  "http://example.com/link2",
  "http://example.com/link3",
  "http://example.com/link4",
  "http://example.com/link5",
  "http://example.com/link6",
  "http://example.com/link7",
  "http://example.com/link8",
  "http://example.com/link9"
  ]
```

Note that you need a comma after every line (except the last one) and each link must be enclosed in straight quotation quotation marks. It's a pain working with quotation marks when using `Concatenate`, so to produce the desired result, in a cell adjacent to your url, type `=Concatenate(CHAR(34),A2,CHAR(34),",")` assuming that your url is in cell `A2`.

Good luck.